# Flutter Firebase Dynamic Link Navigator.push not navigating

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I am trying to implement Firebase Dynamic links in a flutter. But when I click on the link it calls the functions but does not take me to the specified page.

***Code Implementation***

**main.dart**

Main Entry Final for Application

```
void main() {

  Crashlytics.instance.enableInDevMode = true;
  FlutterError.onError = Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;

  runZoned(() {

    runApp(MyApp());
  }, onError: Crashlytics.instance.recordError);



}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    DynamicLinks dynamicLinks = new DynamicLinks();
    dynamicLinks.initDynamicLinks(context);


    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
        SizeConfig().init(constraints, orientation);

        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'APP NAME',
          theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
              brightness: Brightness.light,
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home:SplashScreenMain(),
        );
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**dynamicLinkManager.dart**

Another class to handle Dynamic Links.

```
class DynamicLinks {
  void initDynamicLinks(BuildContext context) async{


    var data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(onSuccess: (dynamicLink)  async {
      print("Main = ${dynamicLink}");
      var deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

      final queryParams = deepLink.queryParameters;

      debugPrint('DynamicLinks onLink $deepLink');
      print("queryParams $queryParams");

      if(DynamicLinksConst.inviteUser == deepLink.path){
        print("Step 1.......Code Works");
        
        /* THIS PART CODE IS NOT WORKING  */
        Login.setActiveContext(context);
        Navigator.push(context,
          EaseInOutSinePageRoute(
              widget: SignupPage()), //MaterialPageRoute
        );
      }else{
        Navigator.push(context,
          EaseInOutSinePageRoute(
              widget: LoginPage()), //MaterialPageRoute
        );
      }
    }, onError: (e) async {
      debugPrint('DynamicLinks onError $e');
    });

  }

 



}
```

**Console Output**
Here is the output you can see that its returning data captured by dynamic link.
I Don't Think it a problem with firebase dynamic link it feels like more of a Navigator problem but I am unable to identify the problem here as this *Navigator* is working properly throughout the project expect here.

**EaseInOutSinePageRoute** just adds animation to navigations.

```
I/flutter (  395): Main = Instance of 'PendingDynamicLinkData'
I/flutter (  395): DynamicLinks onLink https://example.com/abc?para1=dataOne
I/flutter (  395): queryParams {para1: dataOne}
I/flutter (  395): Step 1.......Code Works
```

Comment: It looks like the issue here is with `Navigator.push()` and Dynamic Links works properly. Could you check if it's getting the expected BuildContext to push the target screen?

Comment: @Omatt I think you're right. When I remove my **Authenticator** Class it works fine.  The Authenticator is checking for user data in shared preference and pushing the new page on the base of it. After  3 seconds of wait on the splash screen Authenticator is called? so maybe it's overwriting the main context. How can I manage the context of main even if its overwritten by another page call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the issue here is that the expected BuildContext isn't used  in `Navigator.push()`.

Without a minimal repro, it's difficult to provide a concrete solution. Since you've mentioned that you're using an `Authenticator` class that pushes a new page/screen, it might be safer to manage the screen of the app in a single class. With this, it's easier to manage the BuildContext being used  in `Navigator.push()`. You may check this [sample in this blog post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/everything-you-need-to-know-about-flutter-navigation-d0c5e549b3c#1909) and see if it fits your use case.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this looks promising ( the blog post it makes code much more manageable ), But I resolved it by adding navigatorKey in my material app and using it to navigate. But in long run, I will be changing it to onGeneratedRoute.